# How do I compare chars in if statments in c#

Tags: c#

I am new to C#, but I am trying to create a console application in which the user should be able to press a key in order to adjust one of the bools. Here is  the code for detecting user input:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo keyLetter = Console.ReadKey();
char keyChar = Convert.ToChar(keyWord);
```

I need to have an if statement like this:

```
if (keyChar == a)
{
Do something;
}
```

That doesn't work obviously, but I can't find a way to compare chars like that.
*Note: It doesn't need to be a char, but that seems like the easiest way to do it because converting it to a string returns "System.ConsoleKeyInfo".*

Comment: ```keychar == 'a'```  ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.consolekeyinfo.keychar?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method that you're looking for is [ConsoleKeyInfo.KeyChar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.consolekeyinfo.keychar?view=net-5.0). You can compare chars by wrapping the letter in single quotes (e.g. `'a'`)

```
ConsoleKeyInfo keyLetter = Console.ReadKey();
char keyChar = keyLetter.KeyChar;

if (keyChar == 'a')
{
    Console.Write("a");
}
```